# Intel XDK e o plugin audio

Tags: intel-xdk

Estou tendo problemas para tocar um arquivo mp3 no meu app feito no Intel XDK.

Eu estou usando o plugin Media do cordova, que é o mais indicado para fazer isso, mas o problema é o seguinte: eu não consigo tocar áudios que estão localizados na pasta `www` do meu projeto.

Os tutoriais que vi na internet tocam um áudio de uma url, mas eu quero tocar um áudio que está na pasta `mp3/` dentro do `www`.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que o problema não era com o meu código mas sim com o celular de um amigo meu que estava com problemas.

Tanto o `audio` do HTML5 como o plugin Media do Intel XDK funcionaram agora.

Usando o plugin Media ele carregou direitinho sem precisar usar nenhum protocolo ou a função Webpath.